# Applications of ARCH models

Tags: time-series, self-study, garch

As self-study, I'm interested in learning about [ARCH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_heteroskedasticity) models and its extensions/variations, and I've been looking for journal-published articles about its possible real-life modeling and applications to get a hang of it. However, I've found little-to no articles that use linear univariate ARCH (q) models for their estimation (I've found a few regarding GARCH, ARCH-M, etc.)

Does anyone know (or can anyone recommend) some interesting journal articles that apply exclusively this model on real-life data (finance, economics, politics, society, or other subject), and that are easy to read and understand for a beginner like myself?

Answer (score 3):

At least, we have the original [paper](http://www.econ.uiuc.edu/~econ536/Papers/engle82.pdf) of Engle (1982, *Autoregressive Conditional Heteroskedasticity with Estimates of the Variance of United Kingdom Inflation*), which includes an application that looks at the variance of UK inflation.

The ARCH(p) model, but more often a GARCH(1,1) model, is used as a benchmark in many papers that try to extend the original ARCH and GARCH framework. See e.g. the [GARCH paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304407686900631) of Bollerslev (1986, *Generalized autoregressive conditional heteroskedasticity*).

However, you are right in the statement that ARCH(p) models rarely are applied as the only model. The GARCH(1,1) model is often considered a good benchmark model - the title of the [this paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/jae.800) may explain why (2005, *A forecast comparison of volatility models: does anything beat a GARCH(1,1)?*).

Comment: @RichardHardy Hope this is ok - is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

*[Introduction to (Generalized) Autoregressive
Conditional Heteroskedasticity Models in Time Series
Econometrics](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_14/papers/bryant.pdf) (Wong, 2014)* is a good introduction to ARCH/GARCH models.